# optaplanner workbench default algorithm

Tags: optaplanner

In optaplanner workbench at this time it is not possible to specify the desirable construction algorithm and local search metaheuristic for the solver to use. So, which is the default Construction algorithm and the default local search metaheuristic used ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same one as if you don't specify a `<constructionHeuristic>` or `<localSearch>` etc in an optaplanner config. In 6.4.0.Final that boils down to:

- CH: First Fit.
- LS: Late Acceptance with size 400.

That's a good default, but in future versions, that might be even more sophisticated depending on data size en termination etc.